# Lead Conversion Mapping

Tags: apex

When I convert a lead, the standard lead fields Company and Website are automatically converted to the account fields Account Name and Account Website the way it is described in the following link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lead_conversion_mapping.htm&language=en.

I have a custom object with the same fields Company and Website but when converting to account the fields are not mapped to Account Name and Account Website. Please advise how exactly to map the custom object fields with the respective account fields the way it is done with the lead?

Comment: Are you mimicing Lead object by using this Custom Object?

Comment: No, I have a custom object with its own fileds company and website and would like to know how to map them with the account fileds when converting to account.

Comment: So I am assuming , you have a custom code in place that ensures that once this Custom Object's record is created, a new Account is inserted in the system?

Comment: There is no such custom code.
What I would like to achieve is when I tried to convert my custom object and to be more precise to convert its custom fileds to account during the process of conversion the fileds are not mapped the way it is done with the lead fields. What I would like to know is there a way to map custom object fields to account when converting those fields towards account?

Comment: you ll need a trigger, checkout the answer

Answer (score 2):

Lead Mapping is a standard process divided in 2 parts . [Standard Fields Lead Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lead_conversion_mapping.htm&language=en) and [Custom Fields Lead Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_mapleads.htm&language=en)

This process is not available for a custom object. If you are looking to create an Account from a custom object, You might have to implement a custom code that accomplishes this.

Implement an **'after update'** trigger on this custom object to create account and mapping respective fields in this code itself.

Comment: Hi

I actually found a solution to the problem by using and configuring an object convert. 
Set Up >> Develop >> Custom Settings >> Manage (link for setting ‘Admin
Setting’) and View Installed Packages >> Configure (Object Converter). By using the object converter I was able to map the necessary fields and the convertion to account is working alright so far.

Comment: Now that I've managed to convert the fields in my custom object to account I would like to know how to update the status of the lead automatically. There is a custom field in the Lead called New Lead Status where I need to set it to 'closed' if there is account with the same company name and website. So I am checking programatically the values in the company and website fields and if there is account with the same name the one in the lead in the company or the same website I am trying to set the status of the lead to closed.

Comment: Example: lead company = A and website = B >>> account name = A and website = B >>> change lead status to closed.
or 
lead company = A;
lead website = B;

If((company == account.name) || (website == account.website)){
lead.newLeadStatus = 'closed';
}

I would like to know if this can be achieved without having to write program code.